# Finding the DateTime field that is not initialized

Tags: entity-framework

We are saving more than one entity type in one unit of work. There are many *DateTime* fields in each entity-type. Sometimes, an *SqlDateTime overflow exception* occurs because a *DateTime* field is not initialized.

To find the field/property that causes the problem is an annoying task. Does anybody know a debugging technique to find out which field is causing the problem? To check every field is cumbersome.

Thanks a lot for hints.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the DateTime? nullable type then you can use the property hasValue to check if it is null. If you're using DateTime then I believe it defaults to the min value which is DateTime.MinValue and can be easily checked. The MinValue is something insane like <strike>the year</strike> Jan 1st 0001, so it makes sense that SQL wouldn't like that

If you're taking something out of the db, then a standard null check works fine.

Comment: Hi, yes null values would not cause this problem. But if the value is not set to a proper date, it is a programming error and I am looking for a way to find the programming error. Unfortunately, EF will not tell which field is not initialized properly, only a general exception is thrown. We have many DateTime fields, and it consumes a lot of time finding the entity-property that is not initialized. Do you know a debugging technique to find this miserable field quickliy?